# Linear regression and Estimator returning wrong loses. Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, linear-regression

I implemented this model using Keras, and the result was as expected. Now im trying with Tensorflow and I just can't get it right.
As you can see at bellow my loss is just not right.

what am I doing wrong here?

ps: I prefer to use estimators instead of multiply tensors and etc.

```
X = numpy.array([ 1.1, 1.3, 1.5, 2.0, 2.2, 2.9, 3.0, 3.2, 3.2, 3.7, 3.9, 4.0, 4.0, 4.1, 4.5, 4.9, 5.1, 5.3, 5.9, 6.0, 6.8, 7.1, 7.9, 8.2, 8.7, 9.0, 9.5, 9.6, 10.3, 10.5])

y = numpy.array([ 39.343, 46.205, 37.731, 43.525, 39.891, 56.642, 60.15, 54.445, 64.445, 57.189, 63.218, 55.794, 56.957, 57.081, 61.111, 67.938, 66.029, 83.088, 81.363, 93.94, 91.738, 98.273, 101.302, 113.812, 109.431, 105.582, 116.969, 112.635, 122.391, 121.872])


#reduce salaries to unit of thousands
#Split 70% training, 30% test
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=1)

#Create estimator
feat_cols = [ tf.feature_column.numeric_column('X', shape=[1]) ]
estimator = tf.estimator.LinearRegressor(feature_columns=feat_cols)

#input functions
train_input_func = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn({'X': X_train}, y_train, shuffle=False)
test_input_func = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn({'X': X_test}, y_test, shuffle=False)

#Train and test
estimator.train(input_fn=train_input_func)
train_metrics = estimator.evaluate(input_fn=train_input_func)
test_metrics = estimator.evaluate(input_fn=test_input_func)

#Predict salary for arbitrary years of experience
X_single_data = np.array([4.6])
pred_input_func = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn({'X': X_single_data}, shuffle=False)
single_pred = estimator.predict(pred_input_func)

print('--Train metrics--')
print(train_metrics)
print(' ')
print('--Test metrics--')
print(test_metrics)
```

> --Train metrics--
>
> {'average_loss': 5795.477, 'label/mean': 72.32367, 'loss': 121705.016, 'prediction/mean': 1.2057142, 'global_step': 1}
>
> --Test metrics--

{'average_loss': 7422.221, 'label/mean': 84.588104, 'loss': 66799.99, 'prediction/mean': 1.3955557, 'global_step': 1}

FYI:
This is what I got with keras:
[Link to image](https://www.kaggleusercontent.com/kf/7701684/eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMTI4Q0JDLUhTMjU2In0..GXmz9TfZ6ggQ0VAkb_PQhQ.qiRSLhMrkEV3vbSOm7TNallAudgtF2YILb8Ue8CrMfUFqzRgWrkyt78R21aqvP34qz6hHamz3P3uTUxeq7gs4CeEswfgpERrZMvFiX1-usm8kvkmA1XacQ2QrtHtjjwUvRKyo1WyD-2_oD2l2Kq_ZMhoxiG_BuDn4PVKnDW9fbnKeTC6bwCIVq0ySeUiJlaG.sOzBaCcqc73AYv9Z1WW_xg/__results___files/__results___10_1.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the number of epochs to train together with a batch size. Add these parameters to your definition of the input functions, e.g., in case of train input for linear regression it may look like this

```
train_input_func = \
    tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn({'X': X_train},\
                                       y_train,\
                                       num_epochs=500,\
                                       batch_size=1,\
                                       shuffle=False)
```

After that it should start training and loss function will go down.